# Android: Add Timestamp to URL for WebView

Tags: android, url, webview, timestamp

For starters, I am not a programmer, my wife is making me learn how to program for Android because she wants me to make her some apps to use around the house.

I have a basic app that loads a JPG into a WebView window.  I read that in order to help manage caching it's a good idea to add a timestamp to a URL.

I am not sure how to add a Timestamp into the URL.

This is what I have now:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.website.com/webviewimage.jpg"+"?123");
```

I plan to replace the "?123" with the Timestamp, but I'm not sure how to type this in.  I have this in the beginning of my code so hopefully, I'm thinking I'm halfway there.:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Cheers,

Pat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will put the current time in milliseconds on to the end of your URL.

```
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.website.com/webviewimage.jpg?" + System.currentTimeMillis());
```